# Block everyone, except visitors from specific referrer

Tags: .htaccess

In htaccess, how can i block every visitor, including bots, except those who come from a specific domain or with a specific user agent?

I must protect every page from access, except couple of allowed pages.

everyone who is blocked should receive a custom notice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First allow public pages including the forbidden message. Then allow requests with specific referrer and user agents with the appropriate [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)s and send a status `403` to everything else

```
RewriteEngine on

# allow public pages
RewriteRule ^forbidden.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^public1.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^public2.html$ - [L]

# serve everyone from specific-domain or specific-user-agent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www.specific-domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^specific-user-agent$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everybody else receives a forbidden
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

Comment: For the #allow public pages section, how would you allow for a subdirectory or files in a subdirectory i.e. `RewriteRule ^/lib/css/$ - [L]` or `RewriteRule ^/lib/css/styles.css$ - [L]`

Comment: @Keefer The rules/regular expressions are fine, except for the leading slash. See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42969607/1741542