# Need advice with php to redirect user to 404 if he changes or removes the key or var

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a site:

```
www.abc.com
```

A php file is hosted in another site `www.xyz.com` and the link to the php file is:

```
www.xyz.com/folder/thefile.php
```

I put a php function in `thefile.php`. So to use the file, people have to come to `www.abc.com`. Here I put links as:

```
www.xyz.com/folder/thefile.php?file=123456
www.xyz.com/folder/thefile.php?file=789654 and so on
```

Whenever anyone clicks on these links, the value of the variable 'file' gets called in the php function in `thefile.php` and it is executed and the video or image is displayed.

Now, for example, for first case the value is '123456'. In case a person edits the value '123456' to something like '1234' or '65431' etc, even the php file is shown to them. Also if the user just visits `www.xyz.com/folder/thefile.php` without the variable 'file', even then the php file is shown to them.

Now what I want to do is if a person edits the url or tries to visit only `www.xyz.com/folder/thefile.php` then it should take him to some 404 page or other page.
How do I do this?

Comment: You can use a `.htaccess` to deny visitors unless they come from a specific referrer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671521/block-everyone-except-visitors-from-specific-referrer

Comment: @Starkeen : Greetings! Thank you for this. It worked really good. But there is an issue. I mean in thefile.php there is adsense code placed to display ads. Now previously the clicks and views in this file were tracked I got revenue. After I used this method to deny visitors unless they come from a specific referrer, the ad clicks and views are not being tracked at all. Please help me out with this! What do I need to add or do so that the ad clicks and views get tracked.   Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Sending the user who has no "file" parameter to the 404 page is relatively easy.

```
if (!isset($_GET['file'])){
    header("Location: 404.php");
}
```

I can't see any easy method to verify that a user hasn't tampered with the URL. You could make sure the Referrer is your abc.com website, but that's not the least bit secure since users can modify that.

If I was in your shoes, for lack of a better solution, I'd have abc.com save and send a random hash with the link that sends the user to xyz.com. xyz.com could then poll abc.com to verify that the hash is valid. ABC could return the actual file ID. Users with invalid hashes get a=the redirect. Basically, I'd look for a medium of communication that can go around the user, if you need to certify the link is valid.

Comment: Greetings! I used this method inside my php function and it works for this: If a user tried to visit only www.xyz.com/folder/thefile.php , then it takes them to 404 page. But if the user edits the file value then it stays there only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^folder/thefile\.php$ - [NC,L,R=404]
```

Comment: Greetings! Where should I use this? I mean should I use in www.xyz.com/folder/.htaccess ? or www.xyz.com/.htaccess ? .... And I see that there is code in www.xyz.com/.htaccess ... So can you please tell me where and how should I add this code?

Comment: You can put this in example.com/htaccess bellow or above other rules.