# htaccess rewrite rule in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi i'm trying to create a REST API method in core php

I created a controller class and method class to call my function as per the reference

http://phppot.com/php/php-restful-web-service/

I have my files in sub-folder in my server where i'm currently creating this i face issue on accessing rewrite URL , how can u solve this issue below is the htaccess rule which i tried.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/rest/
# map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^/test/rest/mobile/list/$   /test/rest/RestController.php?view=all [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^/test/rest/mobile/list/([0-9]+)/$   /test/rest/RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

Comment: Is your .htaccess located inside `/test/rest/` sub-directory?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the pattern, because there is no leading slash, see [Per-directory Rewrites](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched)

> **Per-directory Rewrites**
>
> - ...
> - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which *never* has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

So to fix this remove the leading slash in your patterns

```
RewriteRule ^test/rest/mobile/list/$ /test/rest/RestController.php?view=all [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^test/rest/mobile/list/([0-9]+)/$ /test/rest/RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

---

Unrelated, but you don't need `RewriteBase` in this case, because you already use absolute substitution URLs.

Also, [`QSA|qsappend`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) is only needed, if you expect that the requests have a query string.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/rest/
RewriteRule /(.*)/ RestController.php?view=$1
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/ RestController.php?view=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: Rewrite Base is not needed it works without that , Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

I got solution using Rewriting URL tool

[http://www.webconfs.com/web-tools/url-rewriting-tool/](http://www.webconfs.com/web-tools/url-rewriting-tool)